# Internet Explorer Issue with color profiles on rounded corners using images

Tags: css, internet-explorer, colors, rounded-corners

I am using images to provide rounded corners for internet explorer but the images are a slightly different shade than the actual border is in IE. This is not the case in Google Chrome or Firefox.

[image: In Firefox and Google Chrome the div looks like this]

In IE the image corners are a slightly different shade than the rest of the border. I think this is because of "color profiles" but I still don't know how to fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: Hard to help with no images and no code. Also, you have 8 questions asked, and no accepts; you might want to work on that.

Comment: To find out if it is the color profile, go here http://www.gballard.net/psd/go_live_page_profile/embeddedJPEGprofiles.html and rollover the images. If they change, then your browser doesn't support color profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using pngs to create your corner you need to strip the gamma information out for IE. A great tool for this is PNGOptimizer: http://psydk.org/PngOptimizer.php

Comment: That program was amazing Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use images for the borders as well as the corners. The images for the borders should have the same color and format as your corners. Or you could drop the old-school approach and use CSS3 border radius properties along with an IE CSS3 hack such as [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Only Safari 2.0+ and Firefox3.0+ (have to use an addon, but from 3.5 it's supported as default) support embedded color profiles.

You can work around this by using either images or border, not a mixture of both.

I use a rounded border image for IE with conditional comments to setup a new css file and CSS `border-radius` for the "real" browsers :)